# Bootstrap 3 phone number validation

Tags: html, validation, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anybody know if it's possible to validate a phone number (just to check if the value is an integer) in bootstrap v3?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: You can use jQuery along with Bootstrap - http://bootply.com/97285

Answer (score 6):

It´s not a bootstrap thing. Take a look at this one:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
<input type="tel" name="usrtel">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: If anyone tries to use `<input type="tel" ...>` please know that the tel type is currently supported only in Safari 8.

Answer (score 1):

just use class for bootstrap.
check the example below.

```
<input type="text" id="UserMobile" maxlength="14" data-fv-numeric="true" data-fv-numeric-message="Please enter valid phone numbers" data-fv-phone-country11="IN" required="required" data-fv-notempty-message="This field cannot be left blank." placeholder="Mobile No. " class="form-control" name="data[User][mobile]" data-fv-field="data[User][mobile]">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap don't give you any support for validation, you coould use Jquery validation Plugin for that, check [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/)

Comment: No. You should use this for american phone numbers: https://jqueryvalidation.org/phoneUS-method/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for form validation. it will give you a complete form validation solution http://formvalidator.net/#default-validators_email

Comment: You linked to "email" validator.  That page does not contain a "phone" validator.

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic validation format and requirement checks, using HTML+CSS, described at the MDN article for <[input type="tel"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel#Validation)>.